# Getting the correct format of input time in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json, forms, time

i have an input of type time in a form, i'm using the concept of appending, e.g i'm using a div of class: `class="input-append"` , and i have a button to add more than input to the form.

in the controller i have this json :

```
$scope.my_times = {
        time: [
        ]
```

and this is the function which will add the new inputs to the json var:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.my_times.time.push({time_input: ''});
  };
```

then i post the json to my server (php file).

my problem is when i insert the date as it , it will be inserted into the database in this format:`1969-12-31T23:02:00.000Z` , if i use `document.getelementbyID("time_input");` i will enter the date correctly, now what i want is where i can use this concept to store the time form input in the json in the correct way ?!! is my point clear ?! if anything not clear just tell me to justify more.

regards.

Comment: what about this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date ?

Comment: use just a library that helps you to keep dates : http://momentjs.com/